# Google elevation api status messages

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-elevation-api

Can anyone provide me a complete list of status messages for [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start)? For instance `DATA_NOT_AVAILABLE` is not included in the list from Google. [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/intro#ElevationResponses)

The obvious answer would be that elevation is not available for this point, but nearby elevation data is available, and thus any point should be returned with elevation and precision estimates, as is done with other tested points. (Random point for reference: `61.87500,9.40261`).

Given this is the case, I have a follow up question:

> What are the precision boundaries for returning elevation data?

Comment: From the documentation you linked in your question: *When the status code is other than OK, there may be an additional error_message field within the Elevation response object. This field contains more detailed information about the reasons behind the given status code. **Note**: This field is not guaranteed to be always present, and its content is subject to change.*

Comment: Further to that, you gave a point for reference, which for me returns `"elevation" : 284.4114379882812`.

Comment: Thank you @MrUpsidown. In our case there is no additional info within the elevation response object. Also, I posted the wrong point, sorry. I have corrected the point. (61.87500,9.40261)

Comment: Looks like a bug as elevation data is available all over the place except at this precise location. Try filing a new bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853). I don't know how precise you need to be but in case you get such result, you might want to move a few "decimals" away from your point and try again (with the example coordinates, elevation data is available literally 2 meters away).

Comment: Thanks for checking the data points and providing links for follow ups.